# Running Ionic 2 App

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am new to Ionic 2. I cloned one project from github for learning purpose and I am trying to run it locally. Following are the steps that I have used to run the app.

```
1)npm install 
2)ionic serve
```

The original repo was 9MB. After running "npm intall", it creates node_module directory which is more than 200mb. Is there any way to not to have node_module and run app without it?

By running this command it also creates www folder which was not in original repo. Is www required for ionic 2 app?

My second question is how to generate apk file in ionic2? Will my apk file will also have node_module and will it be really large file?

Answer (score 0):

`npm install` will download all the node packages used in the project, so the repo you cloned probably uses some heavy plugins which make the folder weigh 200MB. You cannot run your app without the folder, because the code uses it and you'll get errors like 'module not found'.

The www folder is the output folder where ionic stores all the generated files (converted scss to css, typescript to javascript etc) which it uses to run. So yes, this is required.

Generating an apk can be done with the `ionic build android` command. You need a valid SDK and I think also android studio to do this, though.

Answer (score 0):

Install Ionic

npm install -g cordova ionic

Download 'ANDROID STUDIO', ALSO ADD platform_tool, sdk,ANT, java jdk

after completing all the above

ionic build android [ Creating debug APK File.]